# Plotting mysql data on a real time graph using pyplot

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib, graph, real-time

Plotting mysql data on a real time graph using pyplot

Hi everyone, thanks for reading in advance.
I've been working on a Mysql database, adding a sample every few seconds from a sensor, and also create a table every one, so that all the tables don't become really huge. I've already done this,
what i want know is to plot the last 15 recent samples from the database, always the last 15, i use this query to extract the data
from Mysql:

"Select ColumnName from TableName Where ID > ((Select max(ID) from TableName) - (15 + 1)) order by ID asc;"

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb, time, locale, datetime, pyoo, random, os.path, matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain
from subprocess import Popen
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import mysql.connector as My
import numpy as np

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def Informacion():
        info_dato = round(random.uniform(1,5),2)
        info_dia = time.strftime('%A')
        info_fecha_hora = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        info_lugar = 'CD python'
        return info_dato, info_dia, info_fecha_hora, info_lugar

def Tiempo():
        tiempo_justo_ahora = datetime.datetime.now()
        tiempo_dia = tiempo_justo_ahora.strftime('%A')
        tiempo_fecha = tiempo_justo_ahora.strftime('%x')
        tiempo_hora_actual = tiempo_justo_ahora.strftime('%X')
        tiempo_hoy = tiempo_justo_ahora
        while (tiempo_hoy.isoweekday() > 1):
               tiempo_hoy = tiempo_hoy - (datetime.timedelta(days = 1))
        tiempo_iso = tiempo_hoy.isocalendar()
        tiempo_fecha_inicio = tiempo_hoy.strftime('%x')
        tiempo_fecha_fin = (tiempo_hoy + datetime.timedelta(days=6)).strftime('%x')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return tiempo_dia, tiempo_fecha, tiempo_hora_actual, tiempo_iso[0], tiempo_iso[1], tiempo_fecha_inicio, tiempo_fecha_fin

x = Tiempo()
chequeo = 'El programa fue ejecutado el dia %s %s a las %s' % (x[0],x[1], x[2])
print chequeo
#This is actually just to know when the program was executed, it prints
# "The program was execute the day %(day in letters)s %(date)s %(time)s

Parametros = {
'user': 'XXXX',
'password': 'XXXX',
'host': 'localhost',
'database': 'XXXX',
'raise_on_warnings': True,
'collation': 'utf8_spanish2_ci',}

idioma = "set lc_time_names = 'es_PA';"
tabla = "semana_%s_del_%s" % (x[4], x[3])
crear_tabla = ("create table %s (num_muestra int auto_increment not null,"
            "valor float not null, dia char(10) not null, fecha_hora datetime not null, "
            "punto_muestra char(10) not null, primary key (num_muestra)) character set utf8 collate utf8_spanish2_ci;")
insertar_dato = ("insert into %s (valor, dia, fecha_hora, punto_muestra) values"
            "(%f, '%s', str_to_date('%s','%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s'), '%s')")
existe_tabla = "select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'prueba1' and table_name = '%s';"
buscar_datos = "select %s from %s;"
datos_grafica = ("select %s from %s where num_muestra > " 
            "((select max(num_muestra) from %s) - %d) order by num_muestra asc;")

#...Functions to query...too long, tough if needed please let me know :)

def Formatos_grafica (fig_subplot):
       plt.cla()
       fig_subplot.patch.set_facecolor('lightgrey')
       fig_subplot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formato_fecha)
       fig_subplot.set_title('Prueba 1')
       fig_subplot.set_xlabel('Tiempo')
       fig_subplot.set_ylabel('Valor')
       fig_subplot.grid(True)

formato_fecha = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%A\n%H:%M:%S')
plt.ion()
figura = plt.figure()
ax = figura.add_subplot(111)
Formatos_grafica(ax)
plt.show(block = False)

try:
      #Checking if the database exist, otherwise create it...
      #...Adding the value from the Informacion() function to the database..

      #...Graph part
      ti = Extraer_datos(datos_grafica % ('fecha_hora', tabla, tabla, 16))
      tiempos = matplotlib.dates.date2num(ti)
      valores = Extraer_datos(datos_grafica % ('valor', tabla, tabla, 16))
      Formatos_grafica(ax)
      ax.plot(tiempos, valores)
      ax.scatter(tiempos, valores, color = 'green')
      figura.canvas.draw()
      time.sleep(5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:

      print('\n Se ha ejecutado la salida manual del programa (Control + C)')
      plt.cla()
      plt.clf()
      plt.close()

except Exception as e:

      print('Ha ocurrido un error inesperado \n')
      print(e)
      plt.cla()
      plt.clf()
      plt.close()
```

What i get from the code i made is what i want, a plot with the last 15 (altough sometimes i count 16 for some unknown reason to me, 
doesn't really bother bbut it's kinda weird) but in times around 9 to 12 seconds per graph (adding 5 seconds from the time.sleep(5)
function and also approximately 0.5 since i tested it with the stopwatch on my phone jaja)

So here are my questions regarding the issue:

1. Am I using the matplotlib pyplot function in a bad way?
2. For the function where I erase the axes and format it again before ploting, it's because the times i didn't do this,
   i have an error on the graph, where everytime appears a new plot on the same axes (different plots with different
   colors, that's how I notice). is there's a way to change this?
3. Before the loop, I always get a warning saying: "Futurewarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but
   in the future will perform elementwise comparison
   if self._edgecolors == str('face'):", is this something i should worry about, or a bug since what I searched so far about it,
   most of the times this warning happen it's because of a bug.
4. If there's a way to make the real time plotting faster using matplotlib? I've been reading about Animation, but I'm not really sure if it's really worth, or it will graph at arouund the same time per sample.
5. I'm using plt.ion() to activate the interactive mode, but I've heard that you don't need if you want to use an interface like tinker
   (which i plan to make and use after plotting correctly the samples). Is this true?
6. I tough of a way of not having to always query from the database the 15 newest samples, that involves just doing once prior to the loop and then store it in a list, then everytime I get a new sample, I add iit to the list and drop 1 from the list. Is there's a way to do this?

Best regards

**Edit: Any tips or advise would be appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Here is a good article worth to check: https://moderndata.plot.ly/graph-data-from-mysql-database-in-python/